# Oracle Sql Developer - Query Results won't export when using LISTAGG function

Tags: sql, oracle, csv, oracle-sqldeveloper, listagg

I'm currently working on a project and I'm using my company's Oracle SQL Developer. It's version 1.5.5 if that means anything.
Long story should, I'm trying to export my SQL Results to a CSV, but when I click csv, the export wizard doesn't show up.
When I remove the ListAgg, then it suddenly pops up and everything works as usual.

Is this a version issue or something? Are there any work arounds? The TLDR query is below:

```
LISTAGG( (a.subj || ' ' || a.crse_num || ' ' || a.section), ', ') 
 WITHIN GROUP ( ORDER BY a.subj ) ) AS IP_Courses
```

Everything works normal when I remove the ListAgg ( as well as the concatenation) but when I introduce ListAgg, nothing wants to export. :(

Comment: That's a rather ancient version of SQL Developer.  Have you tried downloading the current version and seeing if that resolves the issue?

Comment: @JustinCave I was hoping to not have to go through my company's IT department, but I guess I have to. Was hoping it was just a certain syntax I was fluffing up. Oh well

Comment: just go to oracle.com/sqldeveloper, download 20.4 and unzip - nothing to actually 'install' as far as a computer is concerned

Comment: If you really want to avoid upgrading (though I'd really suggest upgrading, it's a much better experience these days), you can probably copy and paste from the results grid into Excel and then have Excel save the file as a CSV.  More work but it probably works around the problem.

Comment: Wow, that's from 2009. A lot of sites have an internet use policy prohibiting downloads though, even if they are not actively blocked.